# What is the difference between the US/EU "The Evil Within" and the Japanese version when the Gore DLC has been applied?

Tags: version-differences, the-evil-within

I've heard that there is "Gore DLC" for the Japanese version of *The Evil Within*, so they can get away with a more lenient rating while still allowing players to play the game in all its violent glory.

Is this DLC just bringing it up to the levels of violence found in the western version of the game, or does it go beyond that? Or is the western version less violent/gory than the Japanese version with the Gore DLC?

Comment: Hope my answer helps, @necrosmash :)

Comment: Well, this questions is getting popular @necrosmash ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The Evil Within** is called *Psychobreak* inside Japan. In Japan, the game's graphic violence is actually turned down, disabling features such as dismemberment and full body explosions.

There is a ***Gore DLC*** however

What this does is enable these graphic features, which makes the graphic intensity the same as the Western Versions. There is **NO** dumbing down in both the US/EU versions.

The reason was that if they released the game without dumbing it down, it would have the rating of *"CERO-Z"*, which is the maximum rating inside Japan. To allow a broaden market, they dumbed the intensity so that it would fit the *"CERO-D* rating, which is the maximum rating that allows people to play under the ages of 17. Those above 18 were given a DLC code to activate the gore.

---

## Here are some comparisons:

> **A screenshot with Vanilla Japan version, no DLC. This image shows one enemy hit by explosion**
>   [image]
>   **The game with the Gore DLC/US & EU versions. Noticed the increase gore, blood and dimemberement.**
>   [image]

---

## Here is another comparison

> **Here is an enemy with a hit on the head. This is from the Vanilla Japan Version** [image]
>   **Now look at the same instance with the DLC Activate/US& EU version. Noticed the blood affects, and the dismembered head**
> [image]

---

**TL;DR Version:** The Japan version is censored. Using the DLC activates some gore features that are already in the US & EU versions. This does NOT add any more gore.

---

## Source:

[VG24/7: How The Evil Within looks with gore mode on](http://www.vg247.com/2014/10/14/the-evil-within-pc-ps4-xbox-one-gore-mode-off/)
[SiliconEra: How The Evil Within Looks With Japan’s Gore Mode On And Off](http://www.siliconera.com/2014/10/13/evil-within-looks-japans-gore-mode/)